# Given 12 points in the plane, what is the maximum number of circles that pass through at least 4 of the points?

Tags: geometry, circles

> Given a set of 12 random points in the plane, what is the maximum number of circles that can exist such that they pass through at least 4 of the points?

I'm thinking that using some sort of inversion might help in order to turn all of the potential circles into lines, but can't seem to go any further than that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The title says 3 points, the question says 4 points, so what?

Comment: If you want the maximum number of circles each passing through four of the points, I think you would want to place the points very carefully to maximize the number of circles, not place them randomly.

Comment: @Hume2, that's my bad. It should be 4 points.

Comment: @David K, the point is to find the configuration with the max number of circles.

Comment: At most 495. You may try induction - can you add to each structure a point that will meet the requirement?

Comment: @Moti Why is it just $\dbinom{12}{4}$? I don't think that's physically possible...

Comment: Note that each pair of circles can share up to 2 points. If they share three points, they must be identical because a circle is defined by three points.

Comment: This is the upper limit. I am not claiming it may be achieved.

Comment: Following Hume2 comment  and assuming that you use in all the circles the two points - you may draw at least 10 circles. Note that for 4 points you have one circle - for 5 you can not increase the number - it remains 4. For 6 you have 2. Try to add to the 10 a circle.

Comment: If you arange the points into a regular 3×4 grid, you have 6 small squares. They form 10 rectangles, 2 bigger squares, 2 bigger squares rotated by 45 degrees and 6 isosceles trapezoids. So you can draw at least 26 circles.

Comment: @Hume2 When you put a circle through the vertices of a $3\times1$ rectangle, it also passes through the vertices of two isosceles trapezoids. This happens twice, so there are only $22$ distinct circles in that arrangement.

Comment: Okay, but still the remaining 4 isosceles trapezoids will yield distinct circles, so there are at least 24 distinct circles.

Comment: Do the 12 points have to be distinct? If not, they can be all identical and then you can draw infinitely many circles which pass them all.

Comment: @Hume2 After you eliminate the **four** trapezoids that give duplicate circles (two of them duplicating the circle from **one** rectangle, two duplicating the circle from the **other** $3\times1$ rectangle), only two trapezoids remain that give distinct circles; that's how we get $22$ distinct circles in all. Still an impressively large number of circles. None of my attempts got close to that.

Comment: I have a proof that there can be at most 3 circles for 6 points. Let's have circles $k_1$ and $k_2$ intersecting in points $p_1$ and $p_2$. Points $p_3$, $p_4$ have to lie on $k_1$ and $p_5$, $p_6$ have to lie at $k_2$. Now a circle $k_3$ must have 4 intersections with $k_1$ and $k_2$ and none of the intersections can be at $p_1$ or $p_2$, because there would be less intersections. So we call these intersections $p_3$, $p_4$, $p_5$, $p_6$. A fourth circle would have to intersect $k_1$ and $k_2$ in a different set of four points but we already ran out of points.

Comment: If I change the gaps between columns so the rotated squares become deltoids, the circles from 3×1 rectangles should no longer collide with the circles from the trapezoids.